# Spring Security Google Sign In With Session Rest Service

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-security-rest

I am new to Spring ecosystem, and with the limited knowledge I had with Spring, I understood how Spring Security OAuth2 works.

I need the following functionality, and I think OAuth2 is not what I should be looking at

1. Client sends the `id_token` received from Google sign in via a `POST` request to `/register` endpoint.
2. Backend service validates the `id_token` and identifies user details from Google's Java SDK.
3. Backend service responds with a `set-cookie` header upon successful `id_token` verification.
4. Further client requests containing the `cookie` should be authenticated.

I am even fine with the service authenticating every request using `id_token`

I want the service to be consumable by any client (not only browsers). So, I think OAuth2 is not the right way.

I have watched a lot of videos on youtube and read [this](https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-security-architecture) and got really confused. Please help me understand how to implement this functionality, or at least point me to the right resource to read and understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access from different types of clients (browser, mobile, etc) then the one approach is to go with [JSON Web Token(JWT)](https://jwt.io/).

[refer](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_oauth2_with_jwt.htm)

Comment: Found https://waynestalk.com/en/spring-security-google-signin-jwt-jpa-explained-en/ to be more relevant. Will comment after understanding. Thanks for answering !

Comment: Cool..You are welcome. If it helped you please mark it.